# Selecting record from mySQL via cursors returns an None object

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I am writing a script in python 3.x using mysqlconnector.
What I am trying to achieve right now is to check if there is a record inside my db which may be a duplicate to the one I am analyzing right now. 
I came up with such code:

```
def fill_data(self, db_name, data):
    cursor = self.cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
    isDuplicate = cursor.execute(("SELECT destination FROM {0} WHERE destination = '{1}';")
                                 .format(db_name, data['destination']))

    print(cursor.statement)
    self.commit()
    print(isDuplicate is None)
```

Though I still get isDuplicate as None object. I tried to check via *cursor.statement* what statement is being passed to my db: it turned out that while in script I get None obj while passed in db that query works fine.
I also tried *SELECT COUNT(1) FROM db_name* which also gave me different results.

I am out of ideas: maybe you guys can help me out?

**Update:**

The solution that works for me was:

```
    q = ("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE destination = %s AND countryCode = %s AND prefix = %s")
.format(db_name)
    cursor.execute(q, (data['destination'], data['country_code'], data['prefix']))
    self.cnx.commit()
    isDoubled = cursor.fetchone()
```

So at the end of the day it was all about fetching data from the cursor :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason of your issue is the way you use `execute()` [method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).

Try to make some changes and see what is printed out:

```
def fill_data(self, db_name, data):
    cursor = self.cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
    q = 'SELECT count(*) FROM {} WHERE destination = %s'.format(db_name)
    duplicate_count = cursor.execute(q, (data['destination'], )).fetchall()
    print(duplicate_count)
```

[Why should I provide query parameters this way?](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) (article is on `psql`, but the core principles are the same as in `mysql`)

---

#### update

If you are still receiving `"NoneType" object has no atribute "fetchall"`, then the error is probably here:

```
cursor = self.cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
```

Looks like you are not creating `cursor` at all. I can take a look at it if you post some code about `cnx` creation.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything. What's more: I don't know if I understood right what you are trying to do here, you should've passed data['destination'] instead of db_name in format() method, though.
Both ways (yours or mine with changed parameters) changed nothing except that now I get AttributeError as "NoneType" object has no atribute "fetchall"

Comment: `.format` works as it should - `%s` is not used here, it is used in `execute` method. You can do `print(q)` to see what I mean. I will add a good doc link about providing parameters in queries and my thoughts  about `NoneType`.

Comment: About your update: it is not possible that I am not creating a cursor at that line because I am using the same cursor object later in the same function to add entries to my database. I am currently out of work now but if you insist I can show you initialisation on Monday :)

Comment: that's strange. okay, post the full code and i'll take a look